# Will master theorem be applicable if the base case is not running in constant runtime but in polynomial runtime?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

This is my recursive function:

```
function abc(n):
    if n == 0 
    return xyz(n)

    for i = 1 to n 
        print(xyz(n))

return abc(n/2) + abc(n/2)
```

and xyz() is ϴ(n^3). Will the Master theorem will be valid here? If, yes How will I write it?

Comment: And what is Theta(zero cubed)??

Comment: @MBo It's Theta(n cubed). lower bound for function xyz.

Comment: when n=0, xyz(0)=Theta(0), isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps you could write out more of the recursive function, and say what you think the recurrence relation is for its runtime? At the moment it's hard to know what you're asking because the question appears to be based on the misconception that "xyz(0) runs in polynomial time" means something.

Comment: @PaulHankin  - I have updated it. Can you please discuss what's gonna happen in the above case? . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master theorem concerns recurrence relations of this form:

> T(n) = a * T(n/b) + f(n)

`T` being the recursive procedure, `a` the number of subproblems into which we divide the input `n`, `n/b` the size of each subproblem and `f(n) the cost for the division of the input into subproblems and the combination of the results.

If `n == 0` then `n/b` becomes 0, and so does `a`. This leaves us with:

> T(0) = 0 + f(0)

Since there's no more recursion, it basically comes down to `f(0)`. In your hypothetical case this has a complexity ϴ(n^3).

Since `f(n)` is the cost for the division of `n` into `a` subproblems and the combination of results, `f(0)` would normally have a cost of 0 or a constant. If function `f(n)` has a complexity of ϴ(n^3), then actually for `n == 0` this still leads to a cost of 0 with regards to input size.

The master theorem provides information on the asymptotic bound for `T(n)`, depending on the complexity of `f(n)`, `a` and `b`. This depends on how the complexity of `f(n)` can be expressed using a form that employs `logb(a)`(log with base b of a). The log of 0 is undefined with b > 0.

What it comes down to is that it makes no sense to ask whether the master theorem holds for some specific input. Moreover, the master theorem holds anyway, it just states that depending on `f(n)` you can make some claims about the complexity of `T` or not. This depends on `a` and `b`, so without that information it is senseless to ask. If your `f(n)` has O(n^3) outside of the base case as well (n > 0) then you could make claims about T depending on how that 3 relates to `a` and `b`. For example, if `3 < logb(a)` you'd be sure that T is ϴ(n^(logb(a)).

Suppose that the `a` in your algorithm is `2^n`, then the master theorem could no longer be used to say anything about T's complexity.

EDIT

After your question edit, the form of your recursive procedure has become this:

> T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + f(n)

So `a == 2` and `b == 2` are the parameters in your case, since you divide the input into two subproblems which each get an input that's half of the input doing the recursion. The combination of the two recursive calls is constant (a simple addition `abc(n/2) + abc(n/2)`) and the division of the problems is trivial too, but this part in your case could simulate a ϴ(n^4) algorithm for dividing the input into subproblems:

```
for i = 1 to n 
    print(xyz(n))
```

Note that it's ϴ(n^4) because you stated `xyz(n)` is ϴ(n^3) and you repeat it n times in the loop. So your `f(n) = ϴ(n^4)`.

The master theorem can't really state anything about this. However, if `f(n) = Ω(n^4)` (note the omega here), then `4 > log2(2)` (the logb(a) with b = 2 and a = 2 in your case). In order to make a statement about T's complexity, another condition must now hold, the *regularity condition*. It states that `a * f(n/b) <= k * f(n)` must be true for some k < 1 and sufficiently large n.

So that gives us `2 * f(n/2) <= k * f(n)`. This is true for k < 1/8. This, finally, lets us state that `T = ϴ(f(n))`, so **`T = ϴ(n^4)`**.

Meaning that final part is true if your f(n) (the loop with the xyz call) can be proven to be Ω(n^4) (again, note the omega instead of theta). Since omega is the lower bound, and your f(n) = ϴ(n^4), that should be true.

Comment: I have updated my question, and according to your explanation, the overall complexity does not depend on base case rather it depends on the f(n). Which means the master theorem will hold true in the updated question and my runtime will be `ϴ(n^4)`. and the recursion equation will be  `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n^4` . Is this correct?

Comment: @talos1904 Edited my answer to extrapolate from your extra information. But don't take any of this as truth until it's been verified by someone who hasn't been as long out of algorithmic theory as I've been.

Comment: If `f(n) = ϴ(n^4)` then it means that `f(n) = O(n^4)` and `f(n) = Ω(n^4)`, which implies the above explanation should be true when `f(n) = ϴ(n^4)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, `f(n) = Ω(n^4)` follows from `f(n) = ϴ(n^4)` and that together with the regularity condition lets us state that `T(n) = ϴ(n^4)`. The important parts are knowing the `a` and `b` parameters, and how they relate to the complexity of function `f(n)` that encompasses the division into subproblems and combination of the results. As for the base case, it doesn't require additional recursion so it cuts off at some threshold for input size where the result can be "directly" obtained. So even if you could end recursion for, say, n = 3 instead of n = 0, that's still a hard upper limit for `xyz`.

Comment: Yeah! It all make sense now. Thank you!!

Comment: One man more way to look at it is if base case runtime is higher than the run time of f(n) then the master theorem will not hold. For example in the above case if we remove for loop then the master theorem will not be applicable because base will dominate.

Comment: @talos1904 I believe in that case you won't have a single function f(n) that can be filled in for the general form `T(n) = a * T(n/b) + f(n)`. However, the base case normally won't depend on `n` anyway, because when we get to a base case it will normally be for some known, constant input size. So the base case can still be regarded as a constant.

Comment: Yes! True. I was just considering the hypothetical base case which is not constant. Anyways, Thanks a lot!